# How to insert an element to MongoDB internal list?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following doc stored in MongoDB:

```
{
    name: 'myDoc',
    list: [
        {
            id:1
            items:[
                {id:1, name:'item1'},
                {id:2, name:'item2'}
            ]
        },
        {
            id:2
            items:[
                {id:1, name:'item1'},
                {id:3, name:'item3'}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I found a way to add an element to 'list' using `$addToSet` but I couldn't find a way to add to a specific list of 'items' an item.

e.g.
I get the following:

```
{id:5, name:'item5'}
```

and I want to add it to the element's item in the list with id:2.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

One way of doing it would be with `$push`:

```
db.col.update(
    { name: 'doc', 'list.id': 2 }, 
    {$push: {'list.$.items': {id: 5, name: 'item5'}}}
)
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/

You can also replace `$push` with other operators like (possibly) `$addToSet` to get a similar result to what you are looking for. The main difference is that `$push` will append the new element to the list, whereas `$addToSet` will add the element if it is not there (a unique set of elements).

Comment: How can i do this using mongorepository in JPA

Comment: can you demonstrate how can I do it if the items contain another object and I have to append to an array in that object.

Answer (score 19):

You can use this: -

```
> var toInsert = {id: 5, name: 'item6'}
> db.abc.update(
            { name: 'myDoc', list: { $elemMatch: { id: 2 } } },
            { $addToSet: { 'list.$.items': toInsert } }
  )
```

The `query` part will find the document from the `list` array with `id = 2`. Then we use `$` positional element to add a new element at that array index.

See [`positional $ operator`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_)

---

You can also replace `list: {$elemMatch: {id: 2}}` with just `'list.id': 2`.

But using [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) will be better, when you want to update based on multiple elements of your array. For e.g., when your matching criteria is `id` and some another field in the array say `length`: -

```
list: {$elemMatch: {id: 2, length: 5}}
```

Comment: Footnote, schemas with nested embedded arrays are almost always going to cause problems later since not all operations on lower level elements are possible with the current query language. I'd avoid it.

Comment: above code will throw error if no matching element found. how can we rewrite the query so that error is not thrown