# MONGODB : ADD New Key Value in Array

Tags: mongodb, insert

Below is my array where i want to add new Key Value:---

```
"color" : [
            {
                    "name" : "Blue"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "Red"
            }
    ]

I want to insert new key value as a green color into my array,like this;
"color" : [
          {
                "name" : "Blue"
        },
        {
                "name" : "Red"
        },
        {
                "name" : "Green"
        }]
```

How to add new key value into array,help me,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new `key: val` in an array you can use `$push` in `update` in update

```
db.collectionName.update(query,{ $push: { "array": obj }},option, callback);
```

like:

```
var newObj = {"name":"green"};
db.collectionName.update({_id: givenId},
       { $push: { "color": newObj }},
       function(err, result) {
         if(err) {
           // return  error
         }
        //return success
});
```

to add multiple `key: value` can use `$each` and `$push` like this code

```
var keyValArray= [{"name":"green"},{"name":"white"}];
db.collectionName.update({_id: givenId},
       { $push: { "color": {$each: keyValArray} }},
       function(err, result) {
          if(err) {
             // return  error
          }
          //return success
});
```

Comment: model name means?

Comment: instead of `ModelName` use `db.collectionName`

Comment: "errmsg" : "The field 'color' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: ObjectId('55b85a63e9a22d5624711eb3')}"

its giving this error

Comment: that means in your collection `color` is not an array

Comment: if your `color` is array that you shown in question then should be working. check again your structure. or for that id can check the structure using any GUI

Comment: var newObj = {"name":"yellow"};
db.MYCOL.update({"_id" : ObjectId("55b85a63e9a22d5624711eb3")},
       { $push: { "color": newObj }},
       function(err, result) {
          if(err) {
             // return  error
          }
          //return success
});

i am running like this

Comment: what happening if used `{"_id" :"55b85a63e9a22d5624711eb3"}` without using ` ObjectId(`

Comment: working now,i changed match query..and now i want to add multiple key value how we can do?

Comment: are you using any GUI? like: RoboMongo then try there

Comment: yes i am using mongoBOOSTer ..i want to add multiple?

Comment: should not because I checked also in my end

Comment: its coming like  [
                        {
                                "Name" : "green"
                        },
                        {
                                "Name" : "white"
                        }
                ]
        ]

Comment: no it coming like "color" : [
          {
                "name" : "Blue"
        },
        {
                "name" : "Red"
        },
        [{
                "name" : "Green"
        },{"name":"white"}]]
its coming like this

Comment: you may not used `$each` look at the second query. In this query used `$each`

Answer (score -1):

You can either do a [push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or an [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987365/how-to-insert-an-element-to-mongodb-internal-list) can give you an insight:

ex:

```
db.col.update(
    { name: 'doc'}, 
    {$push: {'color': {name: 'Green'}}}
)
```