# How insert data on mongoDB with condition

Tags: mongodb

i'm new to mongodb is there any option to append new data set into collection.
i.e in 'student',

```
{name: 'Tom', age: 28, marks: [{subject: "English", marks: 90},{subject: "Maths", marks: 100},{subject: "Computes", marks: 20}]}
```

in this 'student' collection how to insert new subject and marks
like

```
{subject:"chemistry", marks:30}
```

I know it may be silly question but pls help me on this
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an element to MongoDB internal list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987365/how-to-insert-an-element-to-mongodb-internal-list)

Comment: yep thanks but @Wernfried Domscheit also made me impressed with his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.students.updateOne(
   { name: 'Tom' },
   {
      $push:
         { marks: { subject: "chemistry", marks: 30 } }
   },
);
```

Note, `$push` will add the element every time you execute the command. If you want to add the element only once then use:

```
db.students.updateOne(
   { name: 'Tom' },
   {
      $addToSet:
         { marks: { subject: "chemistry", marks: 35 } }
   }
);
```

This will append element `{ subject: "chemistry", marks: 30 }` only once. Note, if you run `{ subject: "chemistry", marks: 31 }` then it will be added also.

In case you like to insert `chemistry` just once then you can use this:

```
db.students.updateOne(
   {
      name: 'Tom',
      "marks.subject": { $nin: ["chemistry"] }
   },
   {
      $push:
         { marks: { subject: "chemistry", marks: 30 } }
   }
);
```

Comment: thank you so much @Wernfried Domscheit i also found the $push element ..and u saved me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using Update and [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) as follows

```
db.collection.update(
    { name: 'Tom'}, 
    {$push: {'marks': {subject:"chemistry", marks:30}}}
)
```