# Insert element in array by sibling name in mongodb, node

Tags: mongodb

I want to insert an element in an array by matching the sibling name.
suppose-

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60e544a5e0762b0b2ef6657e"
    },
    "user0": "a",
    "details": [{
        "name": "jon",
        "things": [{
            "name": "car",
            "work": "travel"
        }, {
            "name": "phone",
            "work": "network"
        }]
     },{
        "name": "steve",
        "things": [{
            "what": "car",
            "work": "travel"
        }, {
            "what": "phone",
            "work": "network"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to insert an object in "things" array with where name is "steve"
right now I am doing it like this but is doesn't work

```
collection.updateOne({_id:docs[0]._id}, {$push:{"details.$[]":{things:req.body.data}}});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an element to MongoDB internal list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987365/how-to-insert-an-element-to-mongodb-internal-list)

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters), it gives you the ability to update a specific element in an array with a query, in this case the element that has the name "steve":

```
db.collection.update(
{
   _id:docs[0]._id
},
{
  $push: {
    "details.$[elem].things": req.body.data
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.name": "steve"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4855bfYrJvU)

Comment: You can answer in [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987365/how-to-insert-an-element-to-mongodb-internal-list) if your solution is not available there. and you can close this question by duplicate vote.